# webdriver warning the server did not provide any stacktrace information

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have written `driver.findElement(By.id("kfiDocumentLink")).click();` code for clicking on the button 'KFI Document'.

Please find the HTML code.

```
<a class="button" id="kfiDocumentLink" href="/Quote/KFIDocument/The%20Co-operative%20Bank%20-%20Download%20Mortgage%20Illustration%20(PDF)%20160808104103" target="_blank">Download Mortgage Illustration (PDF)</a>
```

When I run the code, sometimes I am able to click on the button and sometimes I am unable to click the button.

Could someone assist on this please?

Comment: From the sounds of it, the button is not clickable at a certain point. Some buttons are disabled until the page is loaded fully. Could this be the case? Please provide your code for clicking on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually some time when you goes to find element, It would not be present on the `DOM` at that time due to slow internet or other reason, that's why are sometime able to click and sometime not.

To overcome this issue you should try using [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) with [`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-)  to wait before click on element until element visible on the `DOM` and clickable as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("kfiDocumentLink")));
el.click();
```

Comment: I am new to stakeoverflow website as well...:)